# Изменить цену при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

Как при помощи JS правильно изменить любую цену на "123". Приведу пример строк:

```
422.50
12.01
1,244.00
$2,425.00
1,939.00
```

И на выходе, чтоб получилось:

```
123.00
123.00
123.00
$123.00
123.00
```

Цифры обернуты в тег. Но, как проверить внутри каждого элемента на странице наличие цифр и заменить их на "123"? Код для тестов:

```js
let allElems = [...document.querySelectorAll('body *')];
allElems.forEach(item => {

});
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>422.50</div>
  <div>
    <div>12.01</div>
  </div>
  <p>1,244.00</p>
  <a href="#">$2,425.00</a>
  <div><span>$</span><span>1,939.00</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const searchArea = document.querySelector('.test');

searchArea.innerHTML = searchArea.innerHTML.replace(/\d{1,3}(,\d\d\d)*.\d\d/g, '123.00');
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>Крылья, ноги, хвосты. Цена 422.50</div>
  <div>
    <div>не сыпь мне соль на рану, а сыпь её мне в суп. </div>
    <div>12.01</div>
  </div>
  <p>1,101,244.00</p>
  <a href="#">$2,425.00</a>
  <div><span>$</span><span>1,939.00</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Разве маска не будет заменять все точки и запятые на 123?))

Comment: А там должны быть точки и запятые где-то, кроме цен? :)

Comment: Например там может быть какой-то текст. Так что да  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Сейчас вроде бы работает во всех случаях...

Comment: Доброго времени суток. Честно говоря, думал, что придётся огород огородить, а решение настолько простое. Спасибо

Comment: Сначала у меня тоже был огород. Трижды переписывал :))) Зато в регулярках немного разбираться стал...